# Not understanding a "how to prove it" example

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In"How to prove it", I'm having trouble understanding the example (3.6.2) :

Prove that there is a unique set A such that for every set B,    A U B = B.

My question is: why is there a unique set A? Isn't it true for every set A  ⊆ B ?
What am I messing?
 Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: Yep.  True for every $A \subseteq B$.

Comment: I think the question is asking you to prove the existence of atleast one such set.

Comment: $A$ must be the same **for all sets $B$**

Comment: @Tavish No, the question is very clearly asking to prove that there is exactly one such set.

Comment: It's true for every set $A\subseteq B$ that $A\cup B=B$, but the example is asking for a set $A$ such that, *for every set* $B$, $A\cup B=B$ (i.e., $A$ that doesn't depend on the choice of $B$)

Comment: @MorganRodgers True.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’ve misunderstood the question: what’s wanted is the unique set $A$ such that $A\cup B=B$ for **every** set $B$. $A\cup B=B$ if and only if $A\subseteq B$, so you want a set that is a subset of **every** set, and there is only one; what is it?

Comment: The empty set ?

Comment: @tahafen: That’s right.

Comment: thank you. I get it now

Comment: @tahafen: You’re welcome.